# Using selectAll in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, css-selectors

I would like to selectAll X that have the properties Y **and** Z. For instance, I would specifically like to select all lines with an ID of d.id **AND** a target of d.target. It's the 'and' part that I can't figure out; I assumed from the documentation that it should be something like this:

```
selectedLine = d3.selectAll("line[id="+d.id+"]").selectAll(line[target="+d.target+"]");
```

But calling selectAll on a selection always returns an empty selection to me, regardless of the contents (In this case, I'm certain that exists one line with an ID of d.id and a target of d.target).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that `target` is not an attribute that the line element but a data property instead. Besides that, calling `selectAll` on a selection does not return an empty selection: you probably have some other problem. Finally, pay attention to the fact that you are using `selectAll` with an ID, which makes little sense: IDs have to be **unique**.

Anyway, whatever you are using in those attribute selectors, you can simply use multiple attribute selectors:

```
selectedLine = d3.selectAll("line[id='foo'][target='bar']")
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors):

> Multiple attribute selectors can be used to refer to several attributes of an element, or even several times to the same attribute.
>
> Here, the selector matches all SPAN elements whose "hello" attribute has exactly the value "Cleveland" and whose "goodbye" attribute has exactly the value "Columbus":
>
> ```
> span[hello="Cleveland"][goodbye="Columbus"]
> ```